# Neo4j Data Import Slowness

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have to load around 5M Records in the Neo4j DB so I broke the excel into the chunks of 100K the Data is in Tabular Format and I am using CyperShell for that but seems like it has been more than 8 hours and it's still stuck on the first chunk

I'm Using

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'file://aa.xlsx' as row
MERGE (p1:L1 {Name: row.sl1})
MERGE (p2:L2 {Name: row.sl2})
MERGE (p3:L3 {Name: row.sl3, Path:row.sl3a})
MERGE (p4:L4 {Name: row.sl4})
MERGE (p5:L4 {Name: row.tl1})
MERGE (p6:L3 {Name: row.tl2})
MERGE (p7:L2 {Name: row.tl3, Path:row.tl3a})
MERGE (p8:L1 {Name: row.tl4})
MERGE (p1)-[:s]->(p2)-[:s]->(p3)-[:s]->(p4)-[:it]->(p5)-[:t]->(p6)-[:t]->(p7)-[:t]->(p8)
```

Can Anyone Suggest me the changes or alternate Method to load the data in faster way

Data in Excel Format
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. For importing a large amount of data, you should consider using the [import](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/) tool instead of Cypher's `LOAD CSV` clause. That tool can only import into a previously unused database.
2. If you still want to use `LOAD CSV`, you need to make some changes.

   - You are using [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) improperly, and are probably generating many duplicate nodes and relationships as a result. You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63474706/974731) instructive.

     A `MERGE` clause's *entire pattern* will be created if anything in
     the pattern does not already exist.

     So, your last `MERGE` pattern, with its seven relationships, is especially dangerous. It should be split into seven `MERGE` clauses with individual relationships.

     Also, a `MERGE` pattern that specifies multiple properties is likely bad as well. For example, if all `L3` nodes have a unique `Name` value, then it would be safer to replace this:

     ```
     MERGE (p3:L3 {Name: row.sl3, Path:row.sl3a})
     ```

     with something like the following:

     ```
     MERGE (p3:L3 {Name: row.sl3})
     ON CREATE SET p3.Path = row.sl3a
     ```

     *In the above snippet, if the node already exists but `row.sl3a` is different than the existing `Path` value, then no additional node is created. In addition, since the node already existed, the [ON CREATE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.1/clauses/merge/#merge-merge-with-on-create) option does not execute its `SET` clause, leaving the original `Path` value unchanged. You could also choose to use [ON MATCH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.1/clauses/merge/#merge-merge-with-on-match) instead, or even just call `SET` directly if you want to set the value no matter what.*
   - To avoid having to scanning through all the nodes with a given label every time `MERGE` needs to find an existing node, you should create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) or [uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/cypher-intro/schema/#cypher-intro-schema-constraints) for every label/property pair of every node that you are `MERGE`ing:

     - `:L1(Name)`
     - `:L2(Name)`
     - `:L3(Name)`
     - `:L4(Name)`