# Commas in MERGE clause like there are in MATCH clause?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The following works fine in neo4j 4:

```
MATCH (a)-->(b)<--(c), (b)-->(d)
RETURN a
```

But the following returns an error:

```
MERGE (a)-->(b)<--(c), (b)-->(d)
RETURN a
```

Error text:
**Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError**

```
Invalid input ',': expected whitespace, a relationship pattern, ON, FROM GRAPH, USE GRAPH, CONSTRUCT, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE UNIQUE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 22 (offset: 21))
"MERGE (a)-->(b)<--(c), (b)-->(d)"
                     ^
```

If I understand correctly, merge provides a level of upsert functionality. But is merge more restricted in matching capability than match? How do I merge [complex non-linear patterns that require comma separations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34090944/1412255)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *entire* `MERGE` pattern will be created if *any* item in the pattern does not yet exist. So, to be safe, you must always make sure every `MERGE` pattern has only *one* item that might not exist.

This is why it only makes sense for `MERGE` to support patterns with a single term.

For example, instead of this (which is not legal Cypher, anyway):

```
MERGE
  (a:Foo {id: 'a'})-[:BAR]->(b:Foo {id: 'b'})<-[:BAR]-(c:Foo {id: 'c'}),
  (b)-[:BAR]->(d:Foo {id: 'd'})
RETURN a
```

you should actually do this:

```
MERGE (a:Foo {id: 'a'})
MERGE (b:Foo {id: 'b'})
MERGE (c:Foo {id: 'c'})
MERGE (d:Foo {id: 'd'})
MERGE (a)-[:BAR]->(b)
MERGE (b)<-[:BAR]-(c)
MERGE (b)-[:BAR]->(d)
RETURN a
```

Comment: Gotcha. But is there any way to achieve the functionality that merge provides for a complex pattern (i.e. supply a pattern, and if at least one node / relation doesn't exist, create the entire pattern). I'm sure any use cases of this can be handled in other saner ways, but I'm just trying to understand what facilities cypher is giving me out of the box.

Comment: As long as the pattern only has a single term, then `MERGE` will accept it. But if the term is complex, then you'd better know what you are doing. I can't think of a good reason to ever take a risk, frankly.