# Neo4j imports zero records from csv

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j and graph database. While trying to import a few relationships from a CSV file, I can see that there are no records, even when the file is filled with enough data.

```
LOAD CSV with headers FROM 'file:/graphdata.csv' as row WITH row
WHERE row.pName is NOT NULL
MERGE(transId:TransactionId)
MERGE(refId:RefNo)
MERGE(kewd:Keyword)
MERGE(accNo:AccountNumber {bName:row.Bank_Name, pAmt:row.Amount, pName:row.Name})
```

Followed by:

```
LOAD CSV with headers FROM 'file/graphdata.csv' as row WITH row
WHERE row.pName is NOT NULL
MATCH(transId:TransactionId)
MATCH(refId:RefNo)
MATCH(kewd:Keyword)
MATCH(accNo:AccountNumber {bName:row.Bank_Name, pAmt:row.Amount, pName:row.Name})
MERGE(transId)-[:REFERENCE]->(refId)-[:USED_FOR]->(kewd)-[:AGAINST]->(accNo)
RETURN *
```

Edit (table replica):

```
TransactionId   Bank_Name   RefNo   Keyword Amount  AccountNumber   AccountName
12345              ABC       78        X     1000       5421         WE
23456              DEF                 X     2000       5471     
34567              ABC       32        Y     3000       4759         HE
```

Is it likely the case that the Nodes and relationships are not created at all? How do I get all these desired relationships?

Comment: 1. Can you add to your question what your data file looks like (at least the first few rows)? 2. Why do your first 3 `MATCH` clauses not specify any properties -- is that intentional? 3. The `MERGE` pattern in your last query will likely create duplicate relationships.

Comment: @cybersam I have added a sample table.

Answer (score 0):

1. Neither `file:/graphdata.csv` nor `file/graphdata.csv` are legal URLs. You should use `file:///graphdata.csv` instead.
2. By default, `LOAD CSV` expects a "csv" file to consist of [comma separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). You are instead using a variable number of spaces as a separator (and sometimes as a trailer). You need to either:

   - use a *single* space as the separator (and specify an appropriate [FIELDTERMINATOR](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-import-data-from-a-csv-file-with-a-custom-field-delimiter) option). But this is not a good idea for your data, since some bank names will likely also contain spaces.
   - use a comma separator (or some other character that will not occur in your data).

   For example, this file format would work better:

   ```
   TransactionId,Bank_Name,RefNo,Keyword,Amount,AccountNumber,AccountName
   12345,ABC,78,X,1000,5421,WE
   23456,DEF,,X,2000,5471
   34567,ABC,32,Y,3000,4759,HE
   ```
3. Your Cypher query is attempting to use `row` properties that do not exist (since the file has no corresponding column headers). For example, your file has no `pName` or `Name` headers.
4. Your usage of the [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) clause is probably not doing what you want, generally. You should carefully read the documentation, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63495126/974731) may also be helpful.